# Definite articles before abstract nouns which don't relate to any (very) particular instances

Tags: grammar, definite-articles

I know that the title may be little misleading but here is the example which bothers me.

> New approach to (the) ellipticity of linear differential operators

On contrary, I am sure that the following are correct

> It follows from the ellipticity of the Laplace operator. (specified abstract noun)
>
> Ellipticity is closely related to hyperbolicity. (just abstract nouns)

Similarly, I am not sure how to write the following sentence

> I still believe in (the) kindness of people.

Where the following ones are obvious.

> Kindness must be sustained. (specified abstract noun)
>
> The kindness of John is beyond all norms. (just an abstract noun)

Thus, Here is my actual question eventually.

**Question.** Am I specifying abstract nouns in my examples and I should use "the" or is my specification artificial and I should omit "the"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the use of one or more adjectives [*before*](https://englishwithjennifer.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/student-stumper-31-can-abstract-nouns-be-specific/) an abstract noun does not make it specific, i.e., requiring a definite article, a prepositional or participial phrase *after* it does.

> I am impressed by their unbounded kindness. *[possessive pronoun, adjective]*
>
> I am impressed by the kindness of all my former students. *[prepositional phrase]*
>
> I am impressed by the kindness shown to me after the accident. *[participial phrase]*

Comment: It is clear, but unfortunately unrelated to my question. How about the example "I still believe in (the) kindness of people" (here we mean all people)?

Comment: It has everything to do with your question. Prep. phrase = article.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. By the way, I had a hard time reading the first sentence from your answer due to its wierd words order.